# Music Player in TabBar Application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I need to code an app which has a music player in it. The user should be able to control it the whole time he or she is using the application und the music must not stop while navigating through the app. It's done via `UITabBarController`.

What is my approach? Until now, I would have made a "music-player View Controller", but as far as I know, it is only possible to have one View Controller active at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to create singleton class below are the link for more detail.

http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/

Comment: Great one! Thank you so much! It works like a charme. But can I also have the controls embedded in a view on top of the view hierarchy for all view controllers? Where do I define the control view? Also in the Singleton class?

Comment: Look at this for another problem regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842221/make-uiviewcontroller-a-singleton